# Return generic from method

Tags: java, generics

How I can return generic type from method? I wrote like this, but it dont work:

```
private static JsArray<T> convertListToJsArray(Collection<T> list)
```

I need to get Collection as parameter, and return parametrized JsArray.

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450807/java-generics-how-do-i-make-the-method-return-type-generic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must specify the type parameter in front of the return type:

```
private static <T> JsArray<T> convertListToJsArray(Collection<T> list) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare the `T` type. This should work (notice the extra `<T>` before your return type):

```
private static <T> JsArray<T> convertListToJsArray(Collection<T> list)
```

Comment: sorry, it does not, we answered almost simultaneously. michael667 posted his answer a tiny bit quicker than me.