# How to let a function return a "Double" or an "Int"?

Tags: java, function, integer, double, return

I have been working on a project for school. Basically you have to make a script with a couple of scanners. So for instance:

- Return the corresponding ASCII code from a integer, so from a scanner
- Return the surface of a sphere by giving a double.

I now want to make a Scanner class for both functions. But 1 has to be an integer and the second has to be a double. How do I make sure wether the function returns a double or an integer.

I am using the follow code:

```
public static [Heres what goes wrong] vrager (String type, String tekst) {

Scanner vraag = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println(tekst);

type variable = vraag.next();

return variable;
```

So by calling the function would be like: `seconden = (vrager("int", "How many seconds?:));`

But if I would like to let the function work for also doubles it goes wrong cause the function is not expecting to return doubles.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `double` can represent every possible `int` value so return a double.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have two functions with the same name, same parameters but different types.
There are at least a couple of way to implement it, you can do it as:

```
public static Number vrager (String type, String tekst) {
    ...
    Double ret=....
    --- or ---
    Integer ret....
    return ret;
}
```

Look at the documentation for the class [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html)

Another way is to use generics:
[How do I make the method return type generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450807/java-generics-how-do-i-make-the-method-return-type-generic)