# Return type with generics

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to get the following logic to work:

```
public class Wrapper {
    public static class General {
        public void copy(General g) {
            // copy fields
        }
        // General contents.
    }

    public static class Specific extends General {
        // Specific contents.
    }

    public static class GeneralLogic<T extends General> {
        public T load(ResultSet rs) {
            General o = new General();
            // Do stuff
            return new General();
        }
    }

    public static class SpecificLogic<T extends Specific> extends GeneralLogic<T> {
        @Override
        public T load(ResultSet rs) {
            Specific o = new Specific();
            o.copy(super.load(rs));
            // Do stuff
            return new Specific();
        }
    }
}
```

Both return lines result in a compile error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Wrapper.General to T` (`Wrapper.Specific to T` for the second return).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450807/java-generics-how-do-i-make-the-method-return-type-generic?rq=1 might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `T` is a subtype of `General`, an instance of `General` isn't necessarily a `T`. If you want to return a `T,` you'll have to get it from another factory method (as an argument or abstract method), or by accepting a `Class<? extends T>` and instantiate it via reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't be sure that T is a General thus compiler complains. You should be doing something like this:

```
   public  T  ResultSet (ResultSet rs){
        T t=getSomeObject();
        return t;
```

Comment: Do you mean ResultSet instead of double?

Comment: @thSoft yepp... its actually method from my workspace.. i was just pointing where OP was wrong :P

Answer (score 0):

When you say "T extends General", General is the super-class and T is the child class

But during return type you are trying to return Parent(General) object while return type expected is T(Remember, Child class reference cannot hold parent class object).

Change your part of code like this.

```
public static class GeneralLogic<T extends General> {
        public General load(Object rs) {
            General o = new General();
            // Do stuff
            return new General();
        }
    }

    public static class SpecificLogic<T extends Specific> extends GeneralLogic<T> {
        @Override
        public Specific load(Object rs) {
            Specific o = new Specific();
            o.copy(super.load(rs));
            // Do stuff
            return new Specific();
        }
    }
```

**But if it is really important for you to have return type as T, then you need to create an Adapter class which will convert your General(parent) object to child(T) and then return it**

Comment: Generic type in GeneralLogic then doesn't make sense.

Comment: As per @Matt's requirement, I suggested this solution. Can you please explain why it doesn't make sense?

Comment: T in GeneralLogic is never used, so it's IMHO useless.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as follows

```
 public static class General {
    public void copy(General g) {
        // copy fields
    }
    // General contents.
}

public static class Specific extends General {
    // Specific contents.
}

public interface Logic<T extends General>  {
    public T load(ResultSet rs);
}

public static class GeneralLogic implements Logic<General> {

    @Override
    public General load(ResultSet rs) {
        return new General();
    }

}

public static class SpecificLogic extends GeneralLogic {

    @Override
    public General load(ResultSet rs) {
        Specific o = new Specific();
        o.copy(super.load(rs));
        // Do stuff
        return o;
    }
}
```