# Dynamic return type - Java Generics

Tags: java, list, generics, dynamic, types

I have a two similar objects (actually entities). From a function, I get either one of them. So I know which one I got only during the runtime.

I need to do processing on the object I got. Both have same set of processes to be applied. So I would like to write Generic function both both these classes. I tried to write, but I did not get clear idea how to implement this.

```
 List<MyClassA> objAList;
 List<MyClassB> objBList:
 List<ResultA> resultObjAList;
 List<ResultB> resultObjBList;

 objAList = getResult();
 objBList = getResult()

 if ( objAList != null ) {
     // Set of function calls on ObjA to process further. For ex:
    resultObjAList =   doProcess(objAList);

 } else {
     // Same set of function class to process. For Ex:
     resultObjBList = doProcess(objBList);
 }
```

I am about to decide to write two different functions that look similar to do the processing for each of these classes, after a few attempts.

Note the `doProcess` function above. It takes the `objA` or `objB` and return `resultObjA` or `resultObjB`.

I cannot wrap both of these with an interface. So option is ruled out.

`doProcess` looks like this:

```
  List<ResultA> doProcess( List<MyClassA> A ) {
     for ( MyClassList a : A ) {
          a.getSomething();
          doanotherProcess(a.getxya(), a.getABC());
          ....
     }
     return AnotherListOfType_ResultA;
  }
```

Is it possible to write generic function for this?

Comment: Is there any inheritance relation between `MyClassA` and `MyClassB`? And why does your `doProcess` method has `List<MyClassList>` as parameter? What is `MyClassList`?

Comment: Look at [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450807/java-generics-how-do-i-make-the-method-return-type-generic)

Comment: @RohitJain. Those are two different entities but have similar set of fields to be processed on. But not exactly same. `MyClassList`. Its a typo. Updated now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generically map a `List<MyClassA>` input to `ResultA` and `List<MyClassB>` input to `ResultB`, then I can answer that this is not possible: there is no way to express with Java Generics that kind of dependency of result type on input type.

Theoretically, you could parameterize `MyClassA` with `ResultA`, as in `MyClassA<ResultA>`, but it would probably just make a mess out of your code.

Comment: So its better go two different method route?

Comment: The reason I was thinking is, if I write two functions, it will just have repeated code.

Comment: Extract the common code into a third method, so you can reuse it from two type-specific methods.

Comment: I got your point. But even the third method will not solve the problem. Because it needs to accept two types of params again!

Comment: Sorry, if it was my code and I had it all in front of me, maybe I would have come up with something. This way it can't work.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you want to write two functions like
 `public void doProcess(List<ObjectA> list);`   and 
 `public void doProcess(List<ObjectB> list);`   it is not possible, because generics are compile time constructs only, hence the both functions have same erasure.

The best you can do is have a function and cast your object based on some condition.

Comment: Thats, Right. I know. It can't be done. But basically, the idea is writing two functions with different name.

Comment: I hope you could use one rule "Favor Interfaces over Implementation", Have a common interface for both ObjectA and ObjectB, and you can easily invoke based on the type at runtime.

Comment: Thanks. I know that. But in my situ, I can't change it.