# Returning generic type from static method

Tags: java, generics, static, static-methods

I have a static method which is supposed to return results of passed callable, the class of result is not fixed, neither limited. So I am not getting how should I go about defining this static method and how should it be called? 
My follow up question would be what would be the cleaner way, as with this approach I think user is supposed to declare the generic arg at the time of calling the function.

e.g. my function looks something like [I am new to generics, so please bear with me :)]:

```
public static <V> V execute(Callable task) {
        V results = workOnTask(tasks);
        return results;
}
```

Thanks! Needless to say, this is not a homework.

Comment: Is `workOnTask` static too?

Comment: Your declaration should probably be `public static <V> V execute(Callable<v> task)`

Comment: @GGrec: Does that matters? I had put it just to pretend doing some work on specified task.

Comment: Yes it matters. You can't call a non-static method inside a static one. Since it doesn't matter to you, we'll just assume that you're doing work on the task inside the `execute` method, or in another static method. I don't see anything wrong with your solution, though I think @fge's answer is what you need.

Comment: Yes, got you, but that still leaves out below 2 questions:
1. How should the function be called and how should user specify actual class(in-place of V) while calling it?
2. What would be the cleaner way?

Comment: Uh.. oh.. there quite a few cases, depending on what you're trying to do. Has a quick Google search on `java generic methods` helped you in any way so far?

Comment: This is a really good example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450807/java-generics-how-do-i-make-the-method-return-type-generic

Comment: Um, Yes, I did try googling, but in all the cases it was assumed that type of V is one of known class. But my case is different, so I am really worried how can I make user pass correct type of result class for V.

Comment: Note that since both of your methods seem to be static, the type parameter name does not matter. That is, you can have `public static <V> V execute(Callable<V> task)` and `private static <FOO> FOO workOnTasks(...)`