# Java generics NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create a generic MsgRequest Class that can set/get any type of parameter. The intention here is to create a lightweight container for various types of parameters in a Message and pass it to various method calls.

```
public class MsgRequest {

//private HashMap<String, String> _params = new HashMap<>();
private final HashMap<String, Object> _params = new HashMap<>();

/**
 * Returns the value of a specified key, if found, null otherwise.
 * @param key
 * @return 
 */

public <T> T getX(String key) {
    return (T) _params.get(key);
}


/**
 * Sets / replaces a given key in Message params.
 * @param <T>
 * @param key 
 */
public <T> void setX(String key, T element) {
    //TODO: Implement 2nd param as a generic type.
    //_params.put(key, element);
}
```

When I try to test this class like below,

```
@Test
public void testGetString() {
    MsgRequest msg = new MsgRequest();
    String key = "one";
    String val = "This is one.";
    msg.setX(key, val);
    //String s = msg.getX("one");
    assertTrue("result should be string type", msg.getX("one") instanceof String);
}
```

Then it throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodError.

> Testcase: testGetString(com.msgx.MsgRequest.MsgRequestTest):  Caused an ERROR
>   com.msgx.MsgRequest.MsgRequest.setX(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.msgx.MsgRequest.MsgRequest.setX(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
>       at com.msgx.MsgRequest.MsgRequestTest.testGetString(MsgRequestTest.java:48)

Unable to figure out how to fix this exception.  Any suggestions?

Comment: could you derive what `T` is if i just show you `msg.getX("one")`?

Comment: Compiles and runs fine here. Which Java version and compiler are you using? Are you sure you have recompiled your test after making a change to the MsgRequest class?

Answer (score 2):

Make the class `MsgRequest` generic like

```
public class MsgRequest<T> {
    private final Map<String, T> _params = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * Returns the value of a specified key, if found, null otherwise.
     * @param key
     * @return 
     */
    public T getX(String key) {
        return _params.get(key);
    }

    /**
     * Sets / replaces a given key in Message params.
     * @param <T>
     * @param key 
     */
    public void setX(String key, T element) {
        _params.put(key, element);
    }
}
```

And then use it like

```
@Test
public void testGetString() {
    MsgRequest<String> msg = new MsgRequest<>();
    String key = "one";
    String val = "This is one.";
    msg.setX(key, val);
    assertTrue("result should be string type", 
        msg.getX("one") instanceof String);
}
```

Comment: I think your code works only for storing uniformly typed objects in the map.  What if I wanted a Msg object that can store heterogeneous types? I am not worried much about type safety, but wanted a generic container.

Comment: @MupparthyRavindranath Then you can't use generics. Generics are for compile time type checking and homogeneous types. At run-time, they're erased.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar as in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450807/how-do-i-make-the-method-return-type-generic  But getting NoSuchMethodError.

Comment: You didn't pass the Class in. It's not optional. Go read the answer to that question again.

Comment: You are right. I changed now.  But the point is, I get an exception, even before I hit the msg.getX(...) method. The test fails at setX method with that exception.