# Making a function returning the same output-type as input-type

Tags: java, generics

So let's say I have the following generic function which sorts the elements in any `Collection` (e.g. `ArrayList<T>` or `HashSet<T>`):

```
public static <T extends Comparable> Collection<T> sort(Collection<T> a)
{
    List<T> l = a.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
    return l;
}
```

The problem is that when I call the function with the following code and I have an existing variable of type `ArrayList<Integer>` which has some values:

```
counts = (ArrayList<Integer>) sort(counts);
```

When calling the function I have to cast the returned Collection to ArrayList.

Is there a way that I can let the sort function do this conversion for me? So if the input is an `ArrayList`, the output is an `ArrayList`; if the input is a `HashSet`, then the ouput is a `HashSet` etc...

Comment: The method signature for `sort()` should probably return a `List`, since a `Collection` is inherently unsorted. (As is a `Set`) You have to ask - what does it mean to *sort* a HashSet?

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450807/how-do-i-make-the-method-return-type-generic

Comment: @CraigOtis A `Set` makes no assumption of beeing sorted or not. It's neither necessary sorted nor unsorted. A `SortedSet` for example is a `Set` but it *is* sorted...

Comment: @tilois I disagree. While there _are_ certainly implementations of sets that are sorted, the assumption when dealing with a generic set is that its elements are unordered. (Unless you know the details of its implementation, or have been explicitly provided a _sorted_ set.)

Comment: @Héctor: Can you add a few examples of how you would like to call the function you imagine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use generics as @6ton suggests in his answer, but you also need to specify a `Supplier` to your `sort` method, so that you can create the right `Collector`:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>, E extends Collection<T>> E sort(
    Collection<T> a, 
    Supplier<E> factory) {

    return a.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toCollection(factory));
}
```

Then, use your `sort` method this way:

```
List<Float> ordered = sort(unordered, ArrayList::new);
```

This will return an `ArrayList`, but note that the first argument (I've called it `unordered`), can be any `Collection`, i.e. a `HashSet`, `TreeSet`, etc. Similarly, you can return a `Set`, while `unordered` could be a `List` or whatever `Collection`:

```
Set<Float> ordered = sort(unordered, LinkedHashSet::new);
```

Note: as others have stated, it doesn't make sense to sort a `HashSet`, and the same happens with some other collections. While specifying a `Supplier` as a factory for the returned `Collection` won't produce runtime errors, it doesn't mean that the returned `Collection` will always be sorted. For example:

```
Set<Float> stillUnordered = sort(unordered, HashSet::new);
```

In this case, the stream will be collected to a `HashSet`, which doesn't maintain order.

Answer (score -1):

One way to go at it is overriding your method as I did below. This will work if you have a limited number of types you want this convenience for. The `Collection` (or `List`) one will be a catch all in case you need more types.

```
public static <T extends Comparable> Collection<T> sort(Collection<T> a)
{
    // do something;
    return a;
}

public static <T extends Comparable> HashSet<T> sort(HashSet<T> a)
{
    return (HashSet<T>)sort(a);
}

public static <T extends Comparable> ArrayList<T> sort(ArrayList<T> a)
{
    return (ArrayList<T>)sort(a);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way that I can let the sort function do this conversion for me? So if the input is an ArrayList, the output is an ArrayList; if the input is a HashSet, then the ouput is a HashSet etc...

There is no way that you can do this, period.  There is no way to order a `HashSet`.

Given, therefore, that there are collections you *cannot* sort, you must settle for a specific collection as a return type.

Answer (score -4):

You can define your method as

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>, E extends Collection<T>> E sort(Collection<T> a) {
    //return ...;
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> sortedList = sort(arrayList);
```

Comment: I tried your code but it didn't work: I used:
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>, E extends Collection<T>> E sort(E a) {
        Collection<T> var = a.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
        return var;
    }

and got the error: Collection<T> cannot be converted to E

Comment: This approach goes in the right direction, but it's not enough. You need to know how to create the collection to return (the one which is sorted).

Comment: If you use `HashSet<Integer> sortedSet = sort(hashSet);` with the implementation of `sort()` provided in the question, you [pollute the heap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html#heap_pollution), since there's no way for a `List` to be a `Set`.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner true had copied over the OP's example . Removed the HashSet code

Comment: @6ton The problem with your answer is that it pollutes the heap when the returning value of the `sort()` method is assigned to a collection that is not a list, i.e. a `Set`. It will compile without any error or warning but it will throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime. You have changed the example and now `sortedList` is an `ArrayList`, but it could have been a `Set` and it would have compiled fine. Your solution should enforce correctness at the compilation level and not rely on a runtime exception.

Comment: ok. I was only suggesting the method signature. I see that its not compatible with the java 8 collections API.