# How do I pass a class (not a class instance) to a method?

Tags: java, gson, android-volley

I have the following code that I want to generify:

```
// retrieve json data from server and display the data on a card with two lines
private void DisplayClassData(int count, final ArrayList<TwoLineSummaryCardDataObject> tlscdo,
                                 final TwoLineSummaryViewAdapter tlsva) {

    final String url = "https://jsaonurl.com/jsondata";

    // want to generify this so that I can pass any class. But not just *any* class. Just some of my
    // classes that I have set up.
    final GsonRequest gsonRequest = new GsonRequest(url, Myclass1.class, null, new Response.Listener<Myclass1>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Myclass1 myclass1) { // again, this refers back to the line above
            tlscdo.clear();
            Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(act);
            realm.beginTransaction();
            // all of my classes will have a getElement() method which will return a list
            // of objects. Perhaps I need to make a prototype and use implements???
            for (int i = 0; i < myclass1.getElement().size(); i++) { 
                tlscdo.add(new TwoLineSummaryCardDataObject(myclass1.getElement().get(i)));
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(myclass1.getElement().get(i));
            }
            realm.commitTransaction();
            tlsva.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            if(volleyError != null) Log.e("MainActivity", volleyError.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error in Volley", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    );

    // Add the request to the queue
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(gsonRequest);
    VolleyHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(gsonRequest);

}
```

In my data structure, I have seven classes that are all set up the same. How can I set it up so that I can reuse the code and pass any of the classes to it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want to make a factory class of some kind that you could invoke `myFactory.getAllElements(Class<? extends MyBaseClass> clazz)` on - assuming you have a `MyBaseClass` that `MyClass1` etc extend.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom request. Extend the `Request<T>` class, where `<T>` represents the type of parsed response.
In the `parseNetworkResponse` method you can instance one of the seven classes. T should be the parent class of all your seven classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a class, then, well, pass a [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html). Java `Class<T>` object, that is.

You would need to use the superclass or an interface of your view adapters, and change your method signature as follows:

```
private <T> void DisplayClassData(
    int count
,   final ArrayList<T> data
,   final BaseViewAdapter va
,   Class<T> itemClass
)
```

Use `itemClass` to create new instances of the class. Use base view adapter to send notifications as needed. Use `itemClass` in place of `Myclass1.class`.

The caller would then call

```
DisplayClassData(tlsCount, tlscdo, tlsva, TwoLineSummaryCardDataObject.class);
DisplayClassData(esCount, escdo, esva, ExpandedSummaryCardDataObject.class);
... // And so on
```

Comment: What does the "private <T> void" mean? Why the <T> before the void?

Comment: @MrGibbage That's how you define a [method generic on some class `<T>`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/450874/335858).