# Android: Creating shorter version of findViewById - Unchecked cast

Tags: java, android, view, findviewbyid

I wrote a method to get views by id in Android like this:
E.g.

```
Button button = <Button>find(R.id.someId);
```

There is actually no need for < Button>.
This is the method I wrote:

```
protected <T extends View> T find(int id){
    return (T) findViewById(id);
}
```

It works great, but the warning "Unchecked cast" bothers me. How could I get rid if it?
Is this method save?
I was inspired by Kotlin so much, that I wanted to create this nice little method to make the code prettier.

Comment: Hi, if you want prettier code you can always look into ButterKnife by Jake Wharton. https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife

Comment: Wow, this is nice. I ll definitely use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`, It is an annotation to suppress compile warnings about unchecked generic operations (not exceptions), such as casts

According to its [Javadocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html), it can go on local variables; this way, it doesn't even affect the entire method.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is there because you don't know whether the View is really of the type T which confuses the normal android checks.

Why don't you simply do

```
protected View find(int id){
    return findViewById(id);
}
```

and then

```
Button button = (Button)find(R.id.someId);
```

to avoid the cast in the method and using generics.

This is equally short and will not result in this warning.

Comment: In your method you effectively do casting too which makes the whole thing pretty pointless. But I fully agree whith Lev who recommends using Butterknife.

Comment: ok, I came up with this: protected <T extends View> T find(int id, Class<T> type){
        return type.cast(findViewById(id));
    }

Comment: I mean, the whole point was avoid casing expression. so, this solution is actually what I wanted. I found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450807/how-do-i-make-the-method-return-type-generic

Answer (score 1):

I came up with what I was looking for based on this answer:
[How do I make the method return type generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450807/how-do-i-make-the-method-return-type-generic)

```
protected <T extends View> T find(int id, Class<T> type){ 
    return type.cast(findViewById(id)); 
}
```

It allows me to retrieve view like this:

```
Button button = find(R.id.someButton, Button.class);
```

which I think is nice.
Thanks to @Lev for pointing out [JakeWharton/butterknife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) , I ll definitely use it from now on.