# How to declare a method returning generic class?

Tags: java

> I am new to java i have a set of classes which extends AbsEntity class.I have a abstract method which should return a Class object and that Class object should be E extends AbsEntity type...here is how i am trying to declare

```
abstract Class<E externds AbsEntity> E getAbsEntity();
```

This declaration through me error Actually i dont know hw to declare...A method whos return type should be Class type which is E extends AbsEntity Plz help

Comment: Example using Java generics  http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/92/generics/5954/deciding-between-t-super-t-and-extends-t#t=2016122805233370177

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450807/how-do-i-make-the-method-return-type-generic

Comment: I think you wanted something like `static <E extends AbsEntity> E getAbsEntity(Class<E> cls)` and then `cls.newInstance()` will give you an instance.

Comment: Ufffffffff Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be declared before the return type, like so:

```
    abstract <E extends AbsEntity> Class<E> getAbsEntity();
```

Take a Look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) at Oracle docs.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
public <E extends AbsEntity> E yourMethod() {
    //yourObject
    return yourObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
static <E> E yourMethod(){
    AbsEntity absEntity = new AbsEntity();
    return (E)absEntity;
}
```