# How do I return an object as its type from a list of its supertype?

Tags: java, generics

Say I have a class structure like so

```
public abstract class A
{
    public String id;
}

public class B extends A
{
    id = "b";
}

public class C extends A
{
    id = "c";
}

public class test
{
    ArrayList<A> as = new ArrayList<A>();
    a.add(new B());
    a.add(new C());

    public *what goes here* get(String s)//returns a subtype of A, not A
    {
        for(A a : as)
        {
            if(a.id.equals(s))//or a.getClass().toString()
            {
                return a;//but need as subtype of A, not A
            }
        }
        //throw some exception here when id is not found
    }
}
```

How do I make it so that if I ran

```
B b = get("b");
```

I would not get a compiler warning here? I don't want to have ugly instanceof checking all over my code, and explicitly casting to B is also not what I want. I think generics might be the way to go but I'm not very experienced with them.

I know this doesn't work but this is the kind of thing I'm looking for

```
public T extends A get(String s)
```

where T extends A is the return type

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do it with generics.

```
public class B extends A {
    public int n = 2;

    public void doBThing()
    {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}


public class Runner
{
    static ArrayList<A> as = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        as.add(new B());
        as.add(new C());
        System.out.println(get(C.class).getClass().toString());
        System.out.println(get(B.class).getClass().toString());
        get(B.class).doBThing();
    }

    public static <T> T get(Class<T> toGet)
    {
        for(A a : as)
        {
            if(toGet.isInstance(a))
            {
                return toGet.cast(a);
            }
        }
        return (T)(new A());
    }
}
```

I had to use a class parameter instead of a String.

Here method main prints:

```
class C
class B
2
```

Gonna be using this trick a lot more often now!

get() doesn't have return type B but is treated like it does as soon as the parameter is B.class

Comment: nice, something similar to what I did, with Class,  but overcoming type erasure in a way I wasn't aware. +1

Answer (score 0):

A single function may not return more than one type, which has to be known at compile time.

So you cannot do

```
public (A or B) get(...) {}
```

If it wasn't for type erasure, you could use the covariant return type property introduced in Java 5 which would allow you to do:

```
public C get(Class<C> t){
     //check match against t
     return istanceC;
}

public B get(Class<B> t){
    //check match against t
     return istanceB;    
}
```

But you'll get a compile error saying that Class and Class have the same erasure (because they both get up-casted to Class).

**EDIT**

based both on kreinerjm's answer and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450807/how-do-i-make-the-method-return-type-generic), it is actually possible to make the above work by using the following form:

```
public <T extends A> T get(Class<T> type) {
    //check and return
    return (T) a;  

}
```

This way, the cast is safer because you will only be able to get in a T that extends from A.

Comment: Check out my response, I was able to do it with a generic method where the type can be assumed by the compiler given it's type via the parameter.