# Java method to return class subtype (not instance, class itself)

Tags: java, generics

I have a class `BaseViewHolder`, which is a base class, and a subclass of it, `MyViewHolder`.

I have a different abstract class, `BaseAdapter` that requires subclasses to to implement a method that returns a subclass of `BaseViewHolder`. I've tried:

```
protected abstract <T extends BaseViewHolder > Class<T> getViewHolderClass();
```

Then I create a class `MyAdapter`, which is a subclass of `BaseAdapter` and I implement the `getViewHolderClass` method:

```
@Override
protected <T extends BaseViewHolder > Class<T> getViewHolderClass() {
    return MyViewHolder.class;
}
```

But I'm getting:

```
Incompatible types.
Required: Class<T>
Found: Class<path.to.my.package.MyViewHolder>
```

How can I make `getViewHolderClass` return a class that *is* or *is derived from* `BaseViewHolder` (without unnecessary casting to more general classes or `?`, of course)? The closest I've found on StackOverflow is [How do I make the method return type generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450807/how-do-i-make-the-method-return-type-generic) but that involves returning class *instances*, whereas I'm trying to return *a class itself*.

Comment: Can you share `MyAdapter`'s definition?

Comment: @Mureinik `public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter`

Comment: have you not declared Type "T" as path.to.my.package.MyViewHolder? In MyAdapter?

Comment: @NtobekoMkhize what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu I was checking whether you had not set <T extends BaseViewHolder > in our class declaration.

Vulcan has provided the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the `?` wildcard.

```
@Override
protected Class<? extends BaseViewHolder> getViewHolderClass() {
    return MyViewHolder.class;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getViewHolder` method doesn’t need to be generic, it can return `Class<? extends BaseViewHolder>`.

The reason the code doesn’t compile is that the return type is always `Class<MyViewHolder>`, which doesn’t allow calls like `adapter.<AnotherViewHolder>getViewHolder()`, although the generic method signature implies it does.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `MyAdapter`'s `T` as `MyViewHolder`:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter<MyViewHolder> {

    @Override
    protected Class<MyViewHolder> getViewHolderClass() {
        return MyViewHolder.class;
    }

    // Other methods...
```