# Return bounded type is incompatible with a type that matches the bound

Tags: java, generics, bounded-types

I’m pretty sure something like this has been asked but I can’t really find the exact wording, so here it goes.

If I have these three classes:

```
package boundedtypetest;

public class Factory {
    private class ClassA {}

    private class ClassB extends ClassA {}

    public <T extends ClassA> T create() {
        return new ClassB();
    }
}
```

Why does the Java compiler say that `T` and `ClassB` are incompatible in the `create` method?

Comment: you can see an answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450807/how-do-i-make-the-method-return-type-generic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created a generic method by declaring `T` as a type parameter with an upper bound.  With generic methods, you must be aware that the caller can decide what `T` is by passing an explicit type argument to your method.

```
class ClassC extends ClassA {}

ClassC c = new Factory().<ClassC>create();
```

There is no guarantee that the type parameter chosen by the caller, explicitly or implicitly, will match the type of what is returned, and you're returning a `ClassB`.  The compiler cannot guarantee type safety here so this is disallowed.

If you don't need the generics, remove the type parameter off the method and declare `create` to return a `ClassB`, `ClassA`, or `Object`.

If you need the generics, then you must take a parameter of type `Class<T>` and create an instance with it to satisfy the compiler.

```
public <T extends ClassA> T create(Class<T> clazz) throws ReflectionRelatedExceptions 
{
    return clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately in my specific case I can’t use `getConstructor().newInstance()` without a good deal of refactoring. It’s a shame that Java doesn’t support overloading by return type, though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you'll be able to store a `ClassB` in another class that extends `ClassA`

For example you have a `ClassC` which extends `ClassA` same as `ClassB` does, you can store the result of `create()` in a `ClassC` object, but the method would be able to return a `ClassB` instance ? That's why you can't

```
class Factory {

    void method() {
        ClassC c = create();     //This is correct, regarding the return type of the method
    }                            // But it would allow to store ClassB in ClassC : NOPE

    public <T extends ClassA> T create() {
        return new ClassB();
    }

    private class ClassA { }

    private class ClassB extends ClassA { }

    private class ClassC extends ClassA { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because `T` could be any sub-class of `ClassA`. To illustrate, say you have another class `ClassC` that extends `ClassA`

```
class ClassC extends ClassA {
}
```

Now you can never be sure of which subclass of `ClassA` will be used to call this method.

```
class Factory {
    public <T extends ClassA> T create() {
        return new ClassB();
    }
}
```

Here `T` could be `ClassB`, `ClassC`, etc. Hence it is not possible for you to return *one of the possible sub-classes* of `ClassA`

Detailed information can be found in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).