# Return different type of object based on condition using Java

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I've three queries which is

```
SELECT NAME FROM EMP WHERE EMPID=100; // THIS RETURNS A STRING

SELECT DEPTID FROM EMP WHERE EMPID=100; // THIS RETURNS AN INT

SELECT EMPID FROM DEPT WHERE DEPTID=101; // THIS RETURNS A LIST
```

Now I'm trying to write a generic code to return the object, but however I'm able to send only one type i.e. list of object at a high level. Is it possible to send result as it is based on the type?

Here is my code

```
public Object getObjectFromDB(final String query, final Map<Object, Object> inputMap, JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, final Object returnType) throws Exception {

    final List<Object> obj = new ArrayList<Object>();
    try {
        jdbcTemplate.query(new PreparedStatementCreator() {             
            @Override
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
                return con.prepareStatement(query);
            }
        }, new PreparedStatementSetter() {
            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {

            }
        }, new ResultSetExtractor<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,DataAccessException {
                while(rs.next()) {
                    if(returnType instanceof Integer) {
                        obj.add(rs.getInt(1));   
                        break;                        
                    } else if(returnType instanceof String) {
                        obj.add(rs.getString(1));
                        break;
                    } else if(returnType instanceof List) {
                        obj.add(rs.getObject(1));
                    }

                }
                return obj;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

It always returns obj which is a list object even though if I want to trigger first query. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried writing a generic method? See [Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) for more info. This could easily work if you already know the return type you are expecting for any particular set of parameters that you pass to your method.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450807/how-do-i-make-the-method-return-type-generic) describes how to write a method with generic return type.

One possible function protoype can be :

```
public static <T> List<T> getObjectFromDB(final String query, final Map<Object, Object> inputMap, JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, T returnType){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will always return a `List<Object>` as you are declaring it here

```
final List<Object> obj = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

try to check the first element of obj (as it's a list) and its type.