# Generic Method in Java - How to return the param class type as return type

Tags: java, generics

How to return the same classType (2nd param) as return type?

```
public Object getJsonPojo(String fileName, Class classType) {
    try {
        return objectMapper.readValue(new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile()), classType);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now I can call like below only

```
A obj = (A) getJsonPojo("filePath", A.class);
```

I want to have something like below, for example (without casting):

```
A obj = getJsonPojo("filePath", A.class);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make the method return type generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450807/how-do-i-make-the-method-return-type-generic)

Comment: `new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile())` ← Don’t do that.  The URL.getFile() method *does not* return a valid filename.  A resource is not a file at all if the application is packaged as a single .jar file.  Either use getResourceAsStream or, if fileName really is a file outside of the project, avoid the getResource methods entirely and just use FileInputStream.

Comment: filrName is the path of the file insdie resource folder. For example: If file present inside resource/a/b/sample.json, I will specify as "a/b/sample.json"

Answer (score 1):

Use the generic parameter at the method level and the explicit casting.

```
public <T> T getJsonPojo(String fileName, Class<T> classType) {
    try {
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
        return (T) objectMapper.readValue(file, classType);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, the generic type `<T>` can be present at the class level.

In any case, don't use raw `Class` but specify a generic type `Class<T>`.

Comment: You are welcome :) consider marking the answer as accepted to let others know this question has a solution. You are also welcome to ask for details and/or edit your question if you feel so.

Comment: @AbdulBasith Enabling all compiler warnings will inform you of this kind of mistake in the future.

Comment: @VGR I don't get you buddy. Nikolas' answer worked for me. Are you referring something?

Comment: @AbdulBasith When you write `Class` without a generic type, the Java compiler gives you a “raw type” warning.  If you enable all compiler warnings and pay attention to them, you’ll find that you don’t need Stack Overflow’s help as often.

Comment: @Nikolas, we dont need explicit casting while returning value. Just we can mention like below code: return objectMapper.readValue(file, classType);

Comment: yeah gotcha @VGR