# What is wrong with generics usage in Ext-GWT?

Tags: generics, gwt

I have come across some forum postings suggesting that the usage of generics in Ext-GWT is flawed. The postings are:

- http://extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=40759
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523728/why-isnt-google-web-toolkit-more-popular

With the latest release of ExtGWT, do these flaws still hold good?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338887/java-generics-generic-type-defined-as-return-type-only 

A question here which is somewhat illustrative of the generics usage in GXT. Doesn't answer the question, but is another entertaining talking point.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Generics in Ext-GWT is flawed. I do think the extgwt Java coding style is poor and could improve.

The idea behind

`public <T> T getModel() { ...}`

for example, is simply to generify the method to avoid type-casting. This can trip the Java compiler when you chain calls. For instance, if getModel() returns Foo and Foo has a bar() method, you can't do something like:

getModel().bar() since the compiler cannot figure out what object you expect. You can in such cases, provide a hint by doing so:

```
<Foo>getModel().bar();
```

By the way, the eclipse compiler is smarter than the JDK and may not complain when it sees some of these constructs but the JDK compiler will.

There is a huge rewrite of Ext-GWT coming with 3.0 - they get rid of their client event model and support ui-binder for example. Expected this summer I believe.

Comment: That is the precise scenario I was grappling with 2 years ago when I tried ExtGWT ... I agree with your suggestion that the coding style is poor and somewhat fuzzy.

Comment: This answer for a similar question is very relevant here .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338887/java-generics-generic-type-defined-as-return-type-only/338917#338917