# Why is there a warning on this Java generic method definition?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-warnings

I noticed that if I use generics on a method signature to accomplish something similar to co-variant return types, it works like I think it would, except it generates a warning:

```
interface Car {
    <T extends Car> T getCar();
}

class MazdaRX8 implements Car {
    public MazdaRX8 getCar() { // "Unchecked overriding" warning
        return this;
    }
}
```

With the code above, my IDE gives the warning: **"Unchecked overriding: return type requires unchecked conversion. Found: 'MazdaRX8', required 'T'"**

### What does this warning mean?

It makes little sense to me, and Google didn't bring up anything useful.  Why doesn't this serve as a warning-free replacement for the following interface (which is also warning free, as co-variant return types are allowed by Java)?

```
interface Car {
    Car getCar();
}
```

Comment: "warning-free replacement for the following interface"... that interface is already warning free. Subclasses (which includes interface implementors) can make a method's return type more specific.

Comment: @Laurence, thank you, I didn't realize that wasn't clear. I meant that the replacement was not warning free, when I thought that naturally, both should be.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You've made the method generic, so the *caller* gets to say what type should be returned (because the caller can specify the type argument). That's a pretty hard interface to implement properly in Java, where you don't get to find out the type argument at execution time.

For example, consider this:

```
Car mazda = new MazdaRX8();        
FordGalaxy galaxy = mazda.<FordGalaxy>getCar();
```

That's perfectly legal as far as the interface is concerned... but it's obviously not going to work.

Any reason why the *interface* isn't generic instead of the method? Then `MazdaRX8` would implement `Car<MazdaRX8>`:

```
interface Car<T extends Car> {
    T getCar();
}

class MazdaRX8 implements Car<MazdaRX8 > {
    public MazdaRX8 getCar() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 No reason, why it's got to be this way.  Actually in my case, co-variant return types work. But it's good to know about the caller being the significant part.  I just tested your code, and FYI the `<FordGalaxy>` isn't even needed on the call, simply `FordGalaxy galaxy = mazdaRX8.getCar()` is error/warning-free and shows perfectly why what I did was wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it doesn't work that way, and is extremely dangerous to do what you are proposing since there is no way for the compiler to deduce what should be "correct" there. Generic methods usually have the type passed into them by the method parameters, here you don't pass anything in parameterized so `T` could be anything that extends `Car`.

Long answer: Look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338887/java-generics-generic-type-defined-as-return-type-only) for the answer.