# Java. Howto change methods signature

Tags: java, generics, methods, signature

Is it possible to change a methods signature in Java depending on the parameter?

**Example:**

Given a class, with a generic parameter `MyItem<T>`.
Assume this class has a method, which returns `T`
Given a second class 'myReturner()' which contains method `myreturn(MyItem<T>)`.

**Question:**

Can i make `myreturn(MyItem<T>)` return a T object, depending on the generic parameter of MyItem?

I suppose it is not possible, because the signature is set during compile time in Java, and T is not known at compile time.
If so, what is the best way to simulate a method, which will return different objects, depending on parameter?
Is writing an own method for each parameter type the only way?

Comment: As to why it is possible: when compiling Java simply outputs `Object myreturn(MyItem)` as a method, removing any generic information. This method obviously can accept any object.

Comment: As far as I can guess Viruzzo's link should be somewhere at this link instead: docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
private <T> T getService(Class<T> type) {
    T service = ServiceTracker.retrieveService(type);
    return service;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this:

```
<T> T myMethod(MyItem<T> item)
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You can, if you also make the whole class generic to that same type T, something like:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyReturn<T> {

    public T myReturn(ArrayList<T> list){
        return null; //Your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic return type is perfectly well possible. Look for instance here: [How do I make the method return type generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450807/java-generics-how-do-i-make-the-method-return-type-generic) or here: [Java Generics: Generic type defined as return type only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338887/java-generics-generic-type-defined-as-return-type-only)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String bla = myMethod(new MyItem<String>());
}

public static <T> T myMethod(MyItem<T> item) {
    return null;
}

public class MyItem<T> {
    //just a dummy
}
```