# Generic method invocation with <T>

Tags: java, generics, jls

I have a problem with understanding such generic method invocation:

```
object = ObjectGenerator.<T> getObject(objectName);
```

Here comes a context for above situation:

```
class GenClass<T> {

   private T object;

   // ... some code

   public void initObject(String objectName) {
      object = ObjectGenerator.<T> getObject(objectName);
   }
}

class ObjectGenerator {

   public static <T extends Object> T getObject(String name) {
      // some code
      return someObject;
   }
}
```

The question is what role plays `<T>` before `getObject(objectName)` invocation?

Comment: +1 for I didn't see this before.

Comment: I'm not asking about sense of it but just about one line of code. I can change method signature to `<T extends Object> T getObject(String name, Class<T> clazz)` - it doesn't matter. Only this one line with invocation of that method with `<T>` is confusing for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note: in the specific example you have given, `ObjectGenerator.getObject(objectName);` should compile fine.

In some situations, the type inference mechanism can't resolve the fact that in:

```
T object;
object = ObjectGenerator.getObject(objectName);
```

the returned type should be `T`. In such a case, you need give the compiler a little help by explicitly indicating the return type you expect.

Here is a contrived example where you need to explicitly specify the generic type:

```
class Example {
    public static <T> List<T> m1() {
        return m2(Arrays.<T> asList()); //Arrays.asList() would not compile
    }
    public static <T> List<T> m2(List<T> l) {
        return l;
    }
}
```

Comment: Under what situations would the "type inference mechanism" not be able to know what the returned type should be?

Comment: @Jeff I have added an example - the exact situations when this happens depends on the result of applying the [type inference rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.7), which are about 12 pages long in the pdf version of the JLS, so not completely sure to be honest. In the end the way I look at it is: either it compiles without the explicit type and I'm happy or it does not and I just add it...

Comment: Yeah, I got it! This is very good explanation for me and looking at this spec from your link I guess there are many more nasty situations to discover! :)

Comment: I don't quite follow how you justified the omission of the type specification. Maybe I missed something that led to my misunderstanding. I just provided my own answer. Could you please take a look and share your thought?

Comment: The generic type happened to be the return type in that example. In the code at the bottom of my answer it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

`object` can be child of T.

Of course `getObject` should better have been defined:

```
public static <T> T getObject(Class<T> objectClass, String name) {
   return objectClass.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(name);
   //return objectClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
}
```

otherwise there is no type safe construction possible, because of the so called type erasure.

Answer (score 0):

I found somthing here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/338906/443427 it may help you.

From what i read may represent the generic that compiler must use to compute the retuned value type, to pass the generic forward

as a note this also work fine (check the ObjectGenerator differs from T):

```
public class ObjectGenerator<X> {
    public static <T extends Object> Set<T> getObject(String name) {
    // some code
    return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't totally agree with the accepted answer, in which it says:

> In such a case, you need give the compiler a little help by explicitly
>   indicating the return type you expect.

This does not sound right to me. As I understand generic method and type inference, the type provided in square brackets does not directly indicate the return type of the generic method. Rather, the type `T` could be return type, argument type, local variable type associated with the generic method.

Actually, thanks to type inference mechanism, we do not need to specify the type parameter `T` in most cases(not only in some situations). In your example, the `<T>` can be safely omitted from the method invocation `ObjectGenerator.<T> getObject(objectName)` like in most other cases. This is because the type `T` of the generic method can be easily inferred from **the type that the result is being assigned, or returned**. In other words, since you declare `private T object` before the method invocation the type `T` will be successfully inferred as `T`.

My claim can be backed up by the following statement from [a definitive tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html):

> Type inference is a Java compiler's ability to look at each method
>   invocation and corresponding declaration to determine the type
>   argument (or arguments) that make the invocation applicable. The
>   inference algorithm determines the types of the arguments and, if
>   available, the type that the result is being assigned, or returned.
>   Finally, the inference algorithm tries to find the most specific type
>   that works with all of the arguments.

Two examples regarding how the inference works:

```
static <T> T pick(T a1, T a2) { return a2; }
Serializable s = pick("d", new ArrayList<String>());
```

The type `T` is inferred as `Serializable` based on the declared assignee type.

```
public static <U> void addBox(U u, java.util.List<Box<U>> boxes) {}
BoxDemo.<Integer>addBox(Integer.valueOf(10), listOfIntegerBoxes);
```

The type `U` is inferred as `Integer` based on the type of the passed argument(i.e., `Integer.valueOf(10)` is of type `Integer`). Hence, the `<Integer>` can be safely omitted from the method invocation above.

To summarize, unless we are not able to infer the type parameter of the generic method from its argument type or the type that the result is being assigned or returned(when invoking the method), we can safely omit the type specification right before the method invocation.

Answer (score -1):

```
 object = ObjectGenerator.getObject(objectName);
```

always returns Object's object since you are calling a static method. For explicitly getting the generic object you have used for T,in your code,

```
 object = ObjectGenerator.<T> getObject(objectName);
```

`<T>` is used in static context. For non static invocation it is not needed.

Comment: -1 Static context has nothing to do with explicitly providing type arguments.