# Java - Implicit Generics Type Inference Rules

Tags: java

```
import java.util.HashMap;

class Holder
{
    HashMap<String, Object> storage;

    public Holder()
    {
        storage = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    public <T> T get(String key)
    {
        return (T)storage.get(key);
    }

    public void add(String key, Object value)
    {
        storage.put(key, value);
    }
}

public class Test022 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Holder h = new Holder();
        h.add("1", false);
        h.add("2", new String[]{"3", "4", "5", null, null});

        Holder h2 = h.get("2"); // compiles OK ?! fails at runtime with ClassCastException?!

        if (h.get("2")) // compiles OK ?! fails at runtime with ClassCastException?!
        {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }


}
```

See the 2 lines marked with `// compiles OK ?! fails at runtime with ClassCastException?!`. I wonder why these compile OK? Could anyone quote the JLS? How does it infer the type - maybe from the operator (`if`, `assignment`, etc.)?

**EDIT**

Also, why this 2nd example generates a compile error?!

```
import java.util.HashMap;

class Holder
{
    HashMap<String, Object> storage;

    public Holder()
    {
        storage = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    public <T> T get(String key)
    {
        return (T)storage.get(key);
    }

    public void add(String key, Object value)
    {
        storage.put(key, value);
    }
}

public class Test022 {

    public static boolean test(String[] s){
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Holder h = new Holder();
        h.add("1", false);
        h.add("2", new String[]{"3", "4", "5", null, null});

        if (test(h.get("2"))) // This doesn't compile ?!
        {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: related: [Generic type defined as return type only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338887/java-generics-generic-type-defined-as-return-type-only)

Comment: George, this question does not ask help to debug. This is about understanding of java generics. The question in fact asks why this code can be compiled. IMHO this question should be re-opened.

Comment: @AlexR The title isn't helpful to future visitors; who is ever going to search for "Why does that compile OK?"

Comment: Well, so chanve the title to something more helpful

Comment: @AlexR If I were a subject matter expert, I could. It appears you are, and you have the reputation to do so.

Comment: I renamed it. It should be better searchable now.

Answer (score 3):

```
public <T> T get(String key)
{
    return (T)storage.get(key);
}
```

A method with a signature like that will infer `T` based on the calling code, and `T` will be allowed to be anything.

This code gets the object out of `storage` and casts it to whatever type the caller requested.  This *should* give you a compile warning which will tell you that the cast is unsafe, and that warning will be correct for exactly the reason you have discovered.  Java makes this a warning, not a compile error, because it can be necessary in some rare cases and *can* be done safely with some care.

Comment: "This code gets the object out of storage and casts it to whatever type the caller requested" Well, I didn't request anything. Can you quote the JLS please. Some cast is happening here based on the context, I think (based on if operator, the type of the variable in the assignment operator, etc.)

Comment: Yes, you did.  You called `get` and assigned the result to a `Holder` type; that's requesting a `Holder` from `get`.  The JLS doesn't address this case specifically because it's pretty much perfectly normal generics.

Comment: OK, check my 2nd example then (I just added one more example). Isn't that normal generics too? Define normal generics please.

Comment: That looks like Java failing to automatically infer the desired type; I believe you could make that compile with `test(h.<String[]>get("2"))`.

Comment: Exactly. My goal is not to compile it but to understand the formal rules - when does it manage to infer it, and when not i.e. what are the formal rules for that type inference.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.2 is probably the most relevant part of the JLS; "A cast from a type S to a type variable T is unchecked unless S <: T, An unchecked cast causes a compile-time unchecked warning, unless suppressed by the SuppressWarnings annotation "

Comment: Type inference is entirely separate from the ClassCastException issue.  Type inference is when Java can figure out what generic types to use, and different versions of Java have better type inference, and type inference can be fixed by just providing explicit type arguments.  ClassCastExceptions are what you get when you ignore unchecked cast warnings, and are more-or-less orthogonal.

Comment: Right, right, I know why I get the ClassCastException. This wasn't what I wanted to stress on. Thank you.

Comment: That was not at all clear.  In any event, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html is the up-to-date type inference rules; they're extremely complicated, though.

Comment: OK, thanks. Interesting though that in my second example, it doesn't manage to infer the type even though intuitively this inference looks much easier. Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Holder` isn't defined to be generic, instead you've made the methods generic to the caller. I think you wanted

```
class Holder<T> {
    HashMap<String, T> storage;

    public Holder() {
        storage = new HashMap<String, T>();
    }

    public T get(String key) {
        return storage.get(key);
    }

    public void add(String key, T value) {
        storage.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Then, because `Holder` is now generic - you'd specify the type when you create it

```
Holder<String[]> h = new Holder<>();
// h.add("1", false); // <-- Pick a type...
h.add("2", new String[]{"3", "4", "5", null, null});
```

Your posted code is an example of a generic method, and those are covered by [JLS-8.4.4. Generic Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4).

Comment: The OP was putting different types in the original `Holder`, not just `String[]`.

Comment: No, I didn't want that. I created this Holder this way just to demonstrate this weird (for me at least) behavior.

Comment: @peter.petrov You *could* make it a `Holder<Object>` (but then you lose type-checking, and it's almost a [`raw type`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)).