# Java generics confusion with two generic super-types

Tags: java, generics

I have a (poor man's) either-type in Java:

```
public final class Either<L, R> {

    final boolean isLeft;
    final L l;
    final R r;

    private Either(final boolean isLeft, final L l, final R r) {
        this.isLeft = isLeft;
        this.l = l;
        this.r = r;
    }

    // map, right-projection, left-projection, etc.  

    public static <L, R> Either<L, R> left(final L l) {
        return new Either(true, l, null);
    }

    public static <L, R> Either<L, R> right(final R r) {
        return new Either(false, null, r);
    }
}
```

I would like to add a method to join the L or R to an instance of some type `T`:

```
    public <T extends L & R> T join() {
        return isLeft ? (T)l : (T)r;
    }
```

But Java does not like this generic constraint: `T extends L & R`. How can I represent this operation in the Java type system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only do this on an `Either` where the two types are related to the type you want to return. Since this isn't generally the case, you need to do this in a static method (or, at least, some method not on the instance of `Either`):

```
static <T> T join(Either<? extends T, ? extends T> either) {
  return either.isLeft ? either.l : either.r;
}
```

Comment: This is clever. With Java 8's slightly less rubbish type inference it will probably do something useful rather than just return `Object`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider not quite sure what you mean. This would certainly do better than returning `Object` in Java 7, and I would have thought earlier versions too.

Comment: Not sure - I would have thought in even in Java 7 it would require generic type hints in many cases, especially is chained into a series of method calls.

Comment: TBH I'm not sure about what's the idea of this decision. This will not work if I want to do:     `Either<String, Long> either = Either.left("dss");
        Integer join = Either.join(either);`

Comment: @Andremoniy the idea is that it will pick the lower common denominator. So an `Either<Long, Integer>` would return `Number`. This will be useful when types are related - and I would imagine that's the only real use case for `Either` anyway, as either result would need to be treated the same.

Comment: That's true, but it narrows usage of this utility. I'm not sure was it intended to be used only in such cases or not.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I have left out the `map` functions in my example. A common use-case is that you return an `Either<Error, Result`> and then transform both sides to a `String` which is human-readable and `join` the two sides for printing.

Comment: @Andremoniy "I'm not sure was it intended to be used only in such cases" but this is the only way you can do it type-safely. Whether or not you intend to use it in other ways, you can only do what the language allows.

Comment: @AndyTurner type-safety is not something mandatory. Sometime even java base classes resort to type-unsafe code (see collections for instance)

Comment: @Andremoniy can you give an example?

Comment: @sdgfsdh in that case this would work fine. If you require mapping before `either` you could even force it with `static <T, L, R> T join(Either<L, R> either, Mapper<L, T> left, Mapper<R, T> right)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner of course, for instance `ArrayList.toArray(T[] a)` contains unsafe type conversion

Comment: @Andremoniy how is that type unsafe?

Comment: @AndyTurner I mean, that `(T[]) Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, a.getClass())` is unchecked cast, what is absolutely same case as we are talking about in my solution

Comment: And there are tons of such places in se api

Comment: Right - but that's an internal implementation detail. From the point of view of somebody calling the method, it is safe. With your solution, callers of the class are responsible for calling it safely, e.g. they *can* write `IllegalArgumentException j = either.join()`, with `Either<String, Integer> either`. That's not a good design.

Comment: @AndyTurner This is a clever solution. I suppose it is impossible to wrap this is a nice instance method?

Comment: @sdgfsdh the only way it can work for an instance method is if the return type works for all choices of `L` and `R`: you'd have to return `Object`. (Unless you constrain `L` or `R` to extend the other)

Answer (score 0):

The constraint that you are putting on your `T` here can't work. How is the compiler supposed to know that the L l or R r that you put into your Either object are **both** L and R at the same time?!

In other words: you want to your result of `join()` to be *Fruit*; than that would require that the "incoming" L l and R r where both Fruits when you created that object. But what happened when you didn't put an Apple and a Banana into your Either, but an Apple and a Scissor? How do you think you could join them under a common supertype?!

Comment: The user would have to use the projection / map methods to transform the `Scissor` into a `Fruit`. Once both sides inherit from `Fruit`, then they can be joined to get the final result.

Comment: How do you transform a Scissor into a Fruit? It aint a Fruit.

Comment: A more concrete example would be `Either<Error, Result>` transformed to a user-facing message `String`.

Answer (score 0):

You possibly want to describe case when `T` extends `L` **or** `R` (as it obviouslty doesn extend both of them at the same time). But you **can't** do such specification in Java.

Do not overcomplicate this case and do just:

```
public <T> T join() {
    return isLeft ? (T)l : (T)r;
}
```

Comment: This works. Does require the user to use the correct type though. Obviously this provides no compile time type safety.

Comment: That's true, but there are cases when you can not avoid compile time type unsafety.

Comment: See [Andy Turner's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42201894/2071828) - one can get the compiler to do a little more work in this case.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I see, and it looks quite confusing for me. What if my case if `Either<String, Integer>`?

Comment: Then you get `Object`. The only real usecase for `Either` is when the consuming code can treat _either_ response equally so an `Either<String, Integer` doesn't really make sense. An `Either<Result, Error>` where both `extends UserRespose` however, would work well.

Comment: Still not sure, as in my solution this will perfectly work: `String join = either.join();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135574/discussion-between-boris-the-spider-and-andremoniy).

Comment: I wasn't the DV, but: "as in my solution this will perfectly work" Only if `either` is a "left" value - what if it's a "right" value? And what about `Long long = either.join();`? This solution is fundamentally unsafe. See [Joachim Sauer's answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/338917/3788176).

Comment: There is not such term as "fundamentally unsafe". It is safe or not-safe. Both cases are fine and widely used even in JSE libraries