# Java generics error in Linux but not in Windows

Tags: java, generics

I have a class that compiles in Windows, but not in Linux.
The method that doesn't compile is `mapA`.
The error I get is: "error: type argument B is not within bounds of type-variable B".
Why does Windows accept my code but Linux doesn't?
Can I disable this error somehow?

This is the class:

```
/** Either an A or a B. C is some common supertype of A and B. */
public class EitherOr<C, A extends C, B extends C>
{
    private final boolean isA;
    private final A a;
    private final B b;

    protected EitherOr(boolean isA, A a, B b)
    {
        this.isA = isA;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    /**
     * If f(A) is of type D,
     * maps an EitherOr<C, A, B> to an EitherOr<E, f(A), B>,
     * where E is some common supertype of D and B.
     */
    public<E, D extends E> EitherOr<E, D, B> mapA(Function<A, D> f)
    {
        return (EitherOr<E, D, B>)(isA ? ofA(f.apply(a)) : ofB(b));
    }

    /** Creates an EitherOr<C, A, B> which is actually an A */
    public static<C, A extends C, B extends C> EitherOr<C, A, B> ofA(A a) {...}

    /** Creates an EitherOr<C, A, B> which is actually a B */
    public static<C, A extends C, B extends C> EitherOr<C, A, B> ofB(B b) {...}

    /** If is A, returns a, else throws an exception. */
    public A getA() {...}

    /** If is B, returns b, else throws an exception. */
    public B getB() {...}

    public C getValue() {return isA ? a : b;}

    ...
}
```

Comment: Where is the error? On the method signature, or in the method?

Comment: I highly suspect the code is not the same in Windows and Linux.

Comment: Note: you would be much better off writing the conditional expression as an explicit `if/else`. The type inference there could well be a bit hairy (as evidenced by the cast).

Comment: @m0skit0: or the compiler generation or settings are different

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't think Java version affect this specific error.

Comment: @AndyTurner in both.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes, 100% not the same code/environment

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels both machines have java 8.

Comment: what other differences in environment are there to look for?

Comment: But what JDK do they have? Which Javac are you using?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels on linux javac 1.8.0_74. on windows java 1.8 configured in eclipse project settings. not sure how to check exact version.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels on windows jdk1.8.0_60

Comment: I'm dubious as to the value of `C` here. I see that it's used as the return value of the `getValue()` method; but it's quite a lot of extra syntactic baggage to carry around, vs a static method `static <C> C getValue(EitherOr<? extends C, ? extends C> eo)` method (see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42201894/3788176)).

Comment: @AndyTurner Nice!!!

Answer (score 0):

So (after adding `import java.util.function.*;`, a blank line replacing `...`s with `return null;`s) the error is:

```
Main.java:22: error: type argument B is not within bounds of type-variable B
    public<E, D extends E> EitherOr<E, D, B> mapA(Function<A, D> f)
                                      ^
  where B,C are type-variables:
    B extends C declared in class EitherOr
    C extends Object declared in class EitherOr
```

That sounds reasonable. `B` does not necessarily extend `E`, which it is required to. It does extend `C`, but that isn't relevant.

The cast is another indication of a problem.

If this code compiles on any compiler, that compiler has major issues.

Comment: On the other hand, one can always substitute `Object` for `E` as a common superclass of `B` and `D`. In that case, you might accept this code as valid, which is what I think the Windows compiler does. I was thinking maybe there is some command line option for `javac` to specify explicitly how to interpret this kind of code.

Comment: @roel A caller might but isn't constrained to. I don't think you are compiling the code you think you are on that platform.