# Why unchecked warning would not be suppressed

Tags: java, intellij-idea, suppress-warnings

I have several unchecked warnings that I would like to suppress but on run I still see this message:

```
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

I am using the following type of annotation and indeed the warning messages disappear in the IDE source code.

```
@Override @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
public GroundBase<J> getGround() {
    return ground;
}
```

I am distributing my code as a public API and I am wondering if the users would see the message too during its usage.

I am testing my code with *junit*. 
I am using Java 8 and intelliJ 2016.3.6.

I have checked the `-Xlint:unchecked` suggestions details. There are no more un-annotated parts in the code but still the compiler suggestions does not disappear (or decrease).

**EDIT**

to better contextualize one of the warning I am getting, here a simplified, but still relevant, part of the code:

```
abstract public class MORBase<J extends OWLObject>
    implements Descriptor<OWLReferences,J>, MORGround<J>

    @Override @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public GroundBase<J> getGround() {
        return ground;
    }
}

interface Ground<O,J>{
    Ground<J> getGround();
}

interface Descriptor<O,J> {
    <I extends Ground<O,J>> I getGround();
}
```

Here the complete message about it:

```
warning: [unchecked] getGround() in MORBase implements <I>getGround() in Descriptor
public GroundBase<J> getGround() {
                     ^
return type requires unchecked conversion from GroundBase<J#1> to I
where J#1,I,O,J#2 are type-variables:
    J#1 extends OWLObject declared in class MORBase
    I extends Ground<O,J#2> declared in method <I>getGround()
    O extends Object declared in interface Descriptor
    J#2 extends Object declared in interface Descriptor
```

I appreciate suggestions on interface designing but my question is related on why the warning does not get suppressed.

Comment: Did you try compiling with `-Xlint:unchecked`? Maybe the code which is causing the warning is not the same code you've suppressed.

Comment: Why are you suppressing those warnings instead of fixing them? Are you commenting the suppressions with the reasons why they're known to be safe casts, as recommended for example in the book _Effective Java_? Are they actually known to be safe casts? Your example fails to show any unchecked casts, much less to answer these questions.

Comment: The code i post is just an example. My actual methods uses generic and are more complicated, but this is not the main point of my question.

Comment: It's just `-Xlint:unchecked`, no dollar sign. Put in an unchecked operation like `<T> void m() { T t = (T) new Object(); }` to make sure it's working. The compiler will emit a message with the exact code which causes the warning and why.

Comment: with your example the message gets suppressed successfully. The difference between my code is that I have the warning in the returning type of the method, not in the body.

Comment: What version of IntelliJ IDEA is this? 3.6 doesn't sound quite right.

Comment: thanks for the comments, I updated the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Post the exact and complete error message you get with -Xlint:unchecked, and post all the relevant code. Not just the line, without any context, where the warning appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem actually lies with the definition of `getGround()` in `Descriptor`. The type variable `I` is free in the declaration of `getGround()`, meaning that your method is promising to return *whatever type the **caller** chooses*! The only way to return a value of type `I` is by subverting the type system somehow (e.g. by throwing an exception or by returning `null`).

The compiler correctly detects that `I` in the *caller's* use of `getGround()` may be a different type than `J` in the implementation of `getGround()` in `MORBase`, but the compiler is not able to emit any bytecode to check the type (since you're compiling `MORBase`, but the bytecode would need to be inserted into *callers* of `getGround()`). Since it cannot check the type, and cannot insert code to check the type, it instead correctly emits an unchecked warning.

It may be possible to actually suppress this warning by attaching the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation to the declaration of `getGround()` in the `Descriptor` interface, but you really shouldn't do that. Instead, fix your code.

My recommended fix would be to simply drop the type variable `I` in the declaration of `getGround()`, and rely on subtype polymorphism to allow you to simply declare `getGround()` as returning `Ground<O, J>`:

```
interface Descriptor<O,J> {
    Ground<O,J> getGround();
}
```

If that's not possible, and you need to be able to return subtypes of `Ground` in subtypes of `Descriptor`, then you need to add a type parameter to `Descriptor` to ensure the type is correctly propagated to the caller:

```
interface Descriptor<O, J, G extends Ground<O, J>> {
    G getGround();
}
```

Note that, even if the `getGround()` method on the `Descriptor` interface is specified to just return `Ground<O, J>`, it's still possible for subtypes of `Descriptor` to specialize the method to return a more specific subtype. For example, this is totally legal (and safe):

```
interface Descriptor<O, J> {
    Ground<O, J> getGround();
}

public final class FooDescriptor<O, J> implements Descriptor<O, J> {
    @Override
    public FooGround<O, J> getGround() {
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem only arises if you want to enforce some relationship between `FooDescriptor` and `FooGround`. That would require either a *traits* system, which Java doesn't have, or a higher-kinded type constraint, which Java's type system does not support. So if you really need a relationship between `FooDescriptor` and `FooGround`, you need to add another type parameter to associate them. But if you don't strictly need a relationship between them, don't complicate your types by trying to encode one.

Note that this problem is commonly called the "parallel inheritance hierarchy" problem, and there are plenty of existing questions about it on SoftwareEngineering.SE, like [this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58291/duplication-in-parallel-inheritance-hierarchies).

Comment: When you say to fix the code, do you intend for making developers to do not design `Ground`s that would not working with a specific `Description`? This is already not possible since the same generic parameter is cheeked by other methods. I am aware that the parameter should be propagated but consider that this is a very simplified extrapolation of my code and if I am propagating all the parameters it becomes unreadable. Beside, this is a very hided part in the API that external users would never see.

Comment: By the way, the adding of the annotation to the `getGround()` method in the `Description` interface does not suppress the warning.

Comment: @user2497897: See my updated answer. You can have parallel `FooDescriptor` and `FooGround` classes without the need for an incorrect type parameter. And the type parameter on your `Descriptor` interface as you've shown it is *definitely* incorrect because it is not constrained to anything.

Comment: @user2497897: To be clear, what I mean by "definitely incorrect" is this: The type parameter `<I extends Ground<O,J>>` on the `getGround` method in your `Descriptor` interface as you've shown it is constrained only by the *output* of the method. Thus I can say `Descriptor<?, ?> d = ...; AnyClassYouWant a = d.getGround();` and it will "type check" but not actually work. See [Java Generics: Generic type defined as return type only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338887/java-generics-generic-type-defined-as-return-type-only) for more information.