# Java Generics: Returning Bounded Generic Type

Tags: java, generics

I have following the piece of code:

```
public <T extends ParentException> T managedException(Exception cause) {        
    if(ExceptionA.class.isInstance(cause)) {
        return ExceptionA.class.cast(cause);
    } else if(ExceptionB.class.isInstance(cause)) {
        return ExceptionB.class.cast(cause);
    } else if(ExceptionC.class.isInstance(cause)){
        return ExceptionC.class.cast(cause);
    } else {
        return new ExceptionD(cause.getMessage(), cause);
    }
}
```

Here `ExceptionA`, `ExceptionB`, `ExceptionC`, `ExceptionD` are children of `ParentException`.

While compiling, I got the errors:

```
incompatible types: ExceptionA cannot be converted to T
incompatible types: ExceptionB cannot be converted to T
incompatible types: ExceptionC cannot be converted to T
incompatible types: ExceptionD cannot be converted to T
```

But, if I change the code to:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends ParentException> T managedException(Exception cause) {        
    if(ExceptionA.class.isInstance(cause)) {
        return (T) ExceptionA.class.cast(cause);
    } else if(ExceptionB.class.isInstance(cause)) {
        return (T) ExceptionB.class.cast(cause);
    } else if(ExceptionC.class.isInstance(cause)){
        return (T) ExceptionC.class.cast(cause);
    } else {
        return (T) new ExceptionD(cause.getMessage(), cause);
    }
}
```

It works without compilation error.

As mentioned in this answer of the SO thread: [How do I make the method return type generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/450852/576758), casting with `T` is allowed and another pointer is given in this thread: [Java Generics: Generic type defined as return type only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/338887/576758). But my question is: why do I need to use typecasting when the `T` is bounded and all returning objects fall into the specified bound?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is wrong. That's why you get the error. You can call your method with `ExceptionC exceptionC=managedException(ExceptionD d)` and you will end up with a cast `(ExceptionC) exceptionD;` And casting it masks the error but you get it at runtime.

Change your method to:

```
public ParentException managedException(Exception cause) {        
    if(ExceptionA.class.isInstance(cause)) {
        return ExceptionA.class.cast(cause);
    } else if(ExceptionB.class.isInstance(cause)) {
        return ExceptionB.class.cast(cause);
    } else if(ExceptionC.class.isInstance(cause)){
        return ExceptionC.class.cast(cause);
    } else {
        return new ExceptionD(cause.getMessage(), cause);
    }
}
```

You don't need generics here. All these exceptions are also ParentExceptions so you can juse return them. When you think about it you are trying to make the method return different types. Which cannot be done like that because if you have a variable that is initialized from this method you need to know what would be the result. And you know that the result will be ParentException but you can't know which kind of parent exception is that.

The reason behind it is that your method if written like  is not returning ParentException - it is returning T (a subclass). And you can return a different type of subclass and not the one you are trying to get.

In a simpler example if we have:

```
class A {}

class B extends A{  };

class C extends A{  };

public  <T extends A> T test() {        
        return (T) new B();
}
```

we can call it with `C c=test();` we actually try to cast `(C) new B();` which is incompatible but we have masked it and we get the exception at runtime

Comment: The code you proposed in `managedException()` compiles but is helpless : you cast to a specific type but the method returns the parent type.

Comment: Yeah but that's what inheritance is for. You cannot have a method that return different types can you? :) It makes it more generic by changing from Exception to ParentException. Imagine that method returning different types of exceptions (like it actually does) you can assign the result to a variable of class ParentException only. You can't assign it to a subclass because you might get a different subclass

Comment: You can replace all the branches with the following: `return cause instanceof ParentException ? (ParentException) cause : new ExceptionD(cause.getMessage(), cause);`

Comment: agreed I just wanted to make it as close as the original question so the problem is easier to understand

Answer (score 4):

Because

```
ExceptionA a = managedException(new ExceptionB());
```

will crash with a `ClassCastException`. Java infers `T` to be `ExceptionA` and your code will go into the `B` case which will result in a wrong cast.

Java is correct in saying that `ExceptionC` is not a `T` because `T` can be *any* other subtype of `ParentException` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `T` is, in the context of your method, a dynamic type parameter which is inferred by the compiler from the invocation context. It is quite easy to break your method:

```
ExceptionC c = managedException(new ExceptionA());
```

This will fail at runtime in both versions. And this is why the compiler does not accept any of your versions (except the second one, with a Generics warning, which is valid for the very reason I outlined above).

To bind the parameter, you usually add a `Class<T>` parameter:

```
public <T extends ParentException> T managedException(Exception cause, Class<T> targetClass);
```

But I think it is immediately obvious why this would render the method invalid (wild casts from one class to an unrelated other will definitely fail at runtime).

The method itself looks quite a little bit spooky. The only thing different from a no-op cast is the `ExceptionD` construction at the end. Perhaps you should rethink what you really want to achieve - this kind of method does not seem the right way to achieve it.

Another solution: Sometimes using Generics is just not right ;-)

Why not just write

```
public ParentException managedException(Exception cause);
```

This should be exactly what you need, for the use cases I could imagine.