# Why does this code with generics throw a ClassCastException in Java 11?

Tags: java, generics

The code below succeeds in Java 8 but throws a ClassCastException in Java 11. Why did the behavior change?

I could not find any related changes in OpenJDK's Java 9, Java 10 or Java 11 feature sets.

```
public class GenericsExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Car> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(getAnimal());
    }

    static <T extends Animal> T getAnimal() {
        return (T) new Animal() {};
    }

    interface Animal {}

    class Car {}
}
```

Comment: You are trying to add Animal, to Set of Cars... How does that work? O.o

Comment: Are you sure that it did work in Java 8? Because it doesn't make a lot of sense that it would.

Comment: @mypetlion Yes, this exact code runs without problem on jdk1.8.0_201. Of course it does not make a lot of sense, but this difference actually caused a bug in our productive code.

Comment: @jayde this compiles in jdk1.8.0_121 (for example), but of course it throws a ClassCastException at runtime (just tested it). If you are saying this code above fails to produce a `ClassCastException` at runtime in your version, then this is a Bug in that version of java 8

Comment: Interestingly, it does run successfully on ideone - the tooltip on "Java" says "sun-jdk-1.8.0_51", I assume that is used for both comiler and runtime, but cannot say for sure.

Comment: Note that such return-type-only generic  parameters need to be used with extreme care, see also [Java Generics: Generic type defined as return type only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338887/java-generics-generic-type-defined-as-return-type-only). There were several bugs related to type inference when it comes to intersection types and bounded generic parameters

Comment: The cast in `getAnimal()` is never turned into a runtime check, as far  as I know - after erasure, this is just `static Animal getAnimal()`, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: At the call site, the compiler accepts it because `Animal` is an interface, and there might be a `Car` that is also an `Animal`, so it infers `T` to be the interection type of `Car` and `Animal`, which compiles fine - but it should generate a runtime check to verify this. I seems that some versions fail to insert this runtime check at the call site. Compilation fails in all versions I tested if `Animal` is a class.

Comment: Also note that this is a good argument to only supress or ignore "unchecked cast" warnings if you really know what you are doing - `return (T) new Animal() {};` causes such a warning, as the compiler cannot guarantee that your anonymous subtype of `Animal` is really a `T`

Comment: @Hulk Thanks, I agree that this must be a bug in older JDKs that don't emit a `checkcast` opcode at all in this example. I also agree that you should never write code like this. :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed it was a [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8058199) in Java 8, which was fixed in Java 9 - [bugfix](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/357).
In some scenarios, the javac `CHECKCAST` instruction was skipped.

If you are curious, consider those 2 lines of code:

```
Set<Car> set = new HashSet<>(); // line 11
set.add(getAnimal());           // line 12
```

Java 8 bytecode will look like this:

```
 LINENUMBER 11 L1
 ALOAD 1
 ALOAD 0
 INVOKEVIRTUAL UserManagerTest.getAnimal ()LUserManagerTest$Animal;
 INVOKEINTERFACE java/util/Set.add (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (itf)
 POP
```

But Java 9 will look like this:

```
LINENUMBER 11 L1
ALOAD 1
ALOAD 0
INVOKEVIRTUAL UserManagerTest.getAnimal ()LUserManagerTest$Animal;
CHECKCAST UserManagerTest$Car
INVOKEINTERFACE java/util/Set.add (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (itf)
POP
```

The only difference is `CHECKCAST` instruction, which (according to [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.checkcast)) states that *the named class, array, or interface type is resolved. If object can be cast to the resolved class, array, or interface type, the operand stack is unchanged; otherwise, the checkcast instruction throws a ClassCastException*.